# Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /vendor/magento/framework/Session/Validator.php on line 132

Tags: magento2, error, customer-session, frontend-error

Sometimes we get this type of error in production mode

my System info:
**Magento ver. 2.4.6-p1**

**Php Ver. 8.1**

**MariaDB 10.6**

[image]

- 

> Report
> file(ba7302309568648563df8f4293486858d9b2cccd6e8c5a1a5b1398afd1cd5c3f)
> content is bellow

- 

{"0":"Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /vendor/magento/framework/Session/Validator.php on line 132",
"1":"#1 Magento\Framework\Session\Validator->_validate() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Session/Validator.php:86]\n#2 Magento\Framework\Session\Validator->validate() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:193]\n#3 Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#4 Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#5 Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#6 Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php:41]\n#7 Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->start() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:123]\n#8 Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php:14]\n#9 Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]\n#10 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]\n#11 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#12 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170]\n#13 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276]\n#14 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239]\n#15 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]\n#16 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]\n#17 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#18 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170]\n#19 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276]\n#20 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239]\n#21 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]\n#22 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]\n#23 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#24 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170]\n#25 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276]\n#26 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239]\n#27 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]\n#28 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]\n#29 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#30 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:206]\n#31 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:182]\n#32 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276]\n#33 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239]\n#34 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]\n#35 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]\n#36 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#37 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:109]\n#38 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->__construct() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:14]\n#39 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]\n#40 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]\n#41 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#42 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:115]\n#43 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]\n#44 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]\n#45 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:30]\n","url":"/","script_name":"/pub/index.php","report_id":"ba7302309568648563df8f4293486858d9b2cccd6e8c5a1a5b1398afd1cd5c3f"}

Comment: I also just happened to me. If I open the page in different browser it works, so it is obviously related to current user session.

Comment: Anyone found the reason for this problem yet?